# Maven: check for changes in scm

Tags: maven, documentation, maven-scm

Is there a maven plugin which I can use to check if there was a commit since the project had been released the last time?
I want to enforce people to keep up with the project documentation and therefore I want to check during the build process if there have been commits to the documentation docbook project since the last release. If there aren't any the build should fail, because there has been no update of the documentation. 
Or do you have other approaches to automatically assure that people keep documenting?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I'm don't think that each code change should trigger documentation change, so I would not force that. Still I'm interested in what others think, so +1 to your question.

Comment: I don't want to trigger a new documentation compilation for each commit, but only when I'm doing a production release there should be a check if there was a commit in the documentation project since the last release (tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a single Maven plugin to do what you want.  There are a couple of plugins that might work together though. [maven-scm-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) has goals `diff` and `changelog`.  `diff` may be configured to write its output to a file; maybe you could examine the file contents with the [gmaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) or [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html).  The latter has a goal that will fail the build if a file is not within a size range.  You may also write custom enforcer rules if the existing ones don't quite do it.

Comment: I would go for the maven-enforcer-plugin as well. Writing your own rule. From my experience, that works quite well.

Comment: Yes, sounds like a very good approach. Many thanks!